# Flask auto-reload and long-running thread

Tags: python, mod-wsgi, wsgi, flask, werkzeug

I'm implementing a long-running thread within a Flask application. In debug mode, with the reloader activated, the long-running thread is not killed upon reload.

Instead, because the code that creates and starts the thread is run after reloading, each cycle creates an additional thread.

How can I prevent this, other than disabling the reloader?

Will the same happen when running under mod_wsgi, with its auto-reload feature?

**Update**: the long-running thread was actually killed by Werkzeug upon reloading. There is an extra copy, which is due to Werkzeug's reloader taking an extra thread which runs the initialization code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mod_wsgi reloading is described in:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode

In the case of a long running request, by default if it doesn't complete within 5 seconds the process will be forcibly killed anyway. This is to avoid problem of process locking up because a request will not finish.

Comment: Thanks. As I see in the docs you linked to, in daemon mode the entire process is restarted so my thread will die along with it.

Comment: Yes, sorry, forgot to clarify that that 5 second timeout is for daemon mode only. Embedded mode reloading is different again as documented.

Comment: At least in my app, existing thread is not killed, not even after 5 seconds. Maybe something has changed over the years.

Comment: Nothing has changed. More likely you aren't running in mod_wsgi daemon mode. It is a common enough mistake people make. They set WSGIDaemonProcess but then do not set WSGIProcessGroup to actually delegate the WSGI application to run in the daemon process. Thus embedded mode is used instead and that behaves differently.