Kill open Popen handles on Flask dev server restart
I have a Flask app that I'm using to serve a webapp, whose frontend is built using esbuild.
I've managed to configure the Flask server to start the esbuild process in development mode, and to ensure that esbuild is killed when the Flask app is killed, with help from this answer:
from ctypes import CDLL
from signal import SIGKILL

def dies_with_parent():
    return CDLL("libc.so.6").prctl(1, SIGKILL)

if os.environ.get("FLASK_ENV") == "development":
    abs_frontend_path = (Path(__file__) / "path" / "to" / "frontend").resolve()

    # frontend script simply calls `esbuild` with args
    Popen(["npm", "run", "dev-js"], cwd=abs_frontend_path, preexec_fn=dies_with_parent)


This works almost perfectly - my esbuild file watcher spins up on server startup, and all of the handles are cleared out after killing the dev server.
The problem is that "all of the handles" is 1 + (times flask server has restarted)
It seems that, when the dev server restarts, the previous one is not "killed", so the previous Popen instances aren't, either.
I understand that the werkzeug Flask startup process will inevitably call Popen this way a minimum of twice due to the way the app is invoked; I'm willing to have two build processes running. But in a few minutes of development with the current configuration, it quickly becomes 30+
Is there any way for me to possibly

Hook the restart process to kill the processes as the previous server stops
Maintain stateful hold of the previous handles, so that I can kill them in @app.before_first_request
Query all existing Popen handles (if there are any), inspect their commands, and kill them if they match some pattern


Personally, I wouldn't drive esbuild from within your Python code, but by having a single parent process responsible for starting and supervising them as two separate children.

That said... do the solutions given in the answers to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11571656/flask-werkzeug-debugger-process-model-and-initialization-code or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449101/how-to-stop-flask-from-initialising-twice-in-debug-mode work for you? WERKZEUG_RUN_MAIN still exists in today's codebase.
